# Difference between figsize and fig.add_axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I am learning the matplotlib library. One thing I didn't understand is `figsize` and `fig.add_axes([0,0,x,x])` are both doing the same thing, aren't they?

For example:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,2))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0,0,2,2])
```

and

```
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(17,4))
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0,0,0.8,0.8])
```

Both are producing the same plot area. So where is the difference between two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A figure is a container for axes:

- The [`figsize`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib-pyplot-figure) param sets the outer figure dimensions `(width, height)` in inches.
- The [`fig.add_axes()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) method sets the inner axes dimensions `[left, bottom, width, height]` in fractions of [`figsize`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib-pyplot-figure).

So the first example creates an **8×2** outer figure with **16×4** axes (`8*2` and `2*2`):

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,2))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0,0,2,2])
```

And the second example creates a **17×4** outer figure with **13.6×3.2** axes (`17*0.8` and `4*0.8`):

```
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(17,4))
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0,0,0.8,0.8])
```

So the two figures and axes are actually different sizes.

Also note that you probably wouldn't want to use the first example in practice since it creates axes that are larger than the figure container.